# Using WeifenLuo DockPanel Suite

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, dockpanel-suite

I have just downloaded the [WeifenLuo(Dock Panel Suite)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) and trying to work with that but I couldn't find a specific documentation on how to use it.

And I have gone through some of the SO questions and finally got something to get started.

Here is what I have done:
I have created a ToolboxWindow class like shown below:

```
Public Class ToolboxWindow
    Inherits WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockContent

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

And trying to create an instance of this toolbox in this way:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private toolboxWindow As ToolboxWindow

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()

        'Create new ToolboxWindow
        toolboxWindow = New ToolboxWindow()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Show it
        toolboxWindow.Show(DockPanel1, DockState.DockLeft)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the final result it shows me this way?

[image]

1.How to `adjust` the `size` of the `toolbox`.

2.If I have `form2` with the `dock panel` how do I show in the `form1`

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 7):

*Q1 How to adjust the size of the toolbox.*

The DockPanel container has a `DockLeftPortion` property (Right, Bottom and Top too). This specifies the width of the left area as either pixels or a proportion of the available area.
I haven't seen anything that allows it to take on the size of the docked controls.

*Q2 If I have form2 with the dock panel how do I show in the form1*

If you have two top level application forms each with a dock panel, you pass the appropriate dockpanel control as the first parameter to the `Show()` method.

Is this what you meant by Q2?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old post, but whilst looking for something else, I see that I have, just today, found the answer.

---

**How To Resize DockForms**

To resize the forms, here is a way that will let you modify them.  [Look here](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/wiki/Customize-the-FloatWindow). 
Just paste this into the namespace of your main sub (I put mine at the bottom):

```
public class CustomFloatWindow : FloatWindow {
    public CustomFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane)
        : base(dockPanel, pane) {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            MaximizeBox = false;
            MinimizeBox = false;
                            Width = 50;
    }

    public CustomFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane, Rectangle bounds)
        : base(dockPanel, pane, bounds) {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        MaximizeBox = false;
        MinimizeBox = false;
                    Width = 50;
    }
}

public class CustomFloatWindowFactory : DockPanelExtender.IFloatWindowFactory {
    public FloatWindow CreateFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane, Rectangle bounds) {
        return new CustomFloatWindow(dockPanel, pane, bounds);
    }

    public FloatWindow CreateFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane) {
        return new CustomFloatWindow(dockPanel, pane);
    }
}
```

And then, to make it work, paste this into the main form:

```
dockPanel.Extender.FloatWindowFactory = new CustomFloatWindowFactory();
```

---

**How To Show the Docked Panel**

To show the panel docked in the dock-form, you have to create a sort of form-template, and in its code, where it says `Form`, change it to `DockContent`, like this:

Now, in a form which you want to use in the docking panel, modify the code to look like this (notice the `DockContent` as the type, rather than `Form`):

```
namespace mynamespace{
public partial class MyForm: DockContent {
    public dockform_MyForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }
}
}
```

Then, to dock it, we first declare the new form, then create it. I like this:

```
//in your form main sub:
private dockform_MyForm dform_MyForm = new MyForm();

//now, somewhere in your form's class, put this:
public void showMyFormDocked() {
    dform_MyForm = new MyForm();
    dform_MyForm.Show(dockPanel);
}
```

Finally, to show the form, you just call this from anywhere:

```
showMyFormDocked();
```

---

I learned all this from studying the source docs and trying to reproduce them.