# How to Show the Form's Own Icon on a Floating Window using DockPanel and its Extender?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dockpanel-suite

With the [Weifen Luo DockPanel](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite) component, one can add to their .net project the ability to dock forms within other forms.  The component is very well done.

Now, I see from this page at the [project forum at github](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/wiki/Customize-the-FloatWindow) (where this component is now hosted), that it is possible, through the use of this `dock.extender` to allow the floating windows to have a normal winform look, that is, `sizeable` with regular Windows title bar, maximize box, minimize box, etc ([see here, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674266/using-weifenluo-dockpanel-suite/11551374#11551374)).  This also allows for the form's icon to show.

My problem is, and hence my question, is that the icon I assign in the form's properties will show in the designer, but one it runs in debug as a float-panel, a generic form icons appears in its place.

Now, I tried assigning the icon through code (both in the form's own code, and in the main application code too, where the form is called) rather than through properties, and that didn't work either.

So how do I get my own custom icon to show as the form's icon when the form is floated, and the extender is used?  I am using the main docking panel in `DockingWindow` mode.

**[EDIT]**

I think this is a hard question!  It's been 2 days and I've not gotten any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a change to the the FloatWindow class itself to set and update the Icon property internally as the content changes.

I have just checked the change in and it will be included in the 2.7 release of the library.

https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/35

Comment: Thank you for that information.  I will be most interested when that new version is released.  I really like the DockPanel Suite.

Comment: If anyone is following this thread, Mr. roken has updated the library! - @roken, I placed this in the formload: `this.Icon = Properties.Resources.myicon;` but it doesn't seem to take.